# Why is safeframe.googlesyndication trying to access Camera and Microphone?

Tags: content-security-policy, adsense

I was checking something on my website, and using Safari's JavaScript console to look for clues.  While doing this, I discovered a troubling thing, that an iframe from `HEX-STRING.safeframe.googlesyndication.com` tried to access the Camera and Microphone.

I believe `googlesyndication.com` is part of Google Ads.  The site (`techsparx.com`) is using Ezoic's advertising service, FWIW.

I've attached an image of the JavaScript console messages.  You see that a feature policy check failed for both Camera and Microphone, from a script named `talon-1.0.37.js`.  On another reload of the page, I got the same message, plus similar messages from `inside.js`.  The URL's for these scripts are:

- https://cdn.js7k.com/rq/iv/inside.js
- https://cdn.js7k.com/ix/talon-1.0.37.js

What I'm alarmed about is the personal privacy implications.  Why is an advertisement trying to access my camera and microphone?  I can think of all kinds of nefarious purposes for trying that access.  Fortunately the defaults on the browser -- Safari -- prevented it.

[image]